# In JavaScript, how do I clear the interval if the user gets the answer right?

Tags: javascript, timeout, cleartimeout

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Clear Interval If</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/5.4.0/bootbox.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
    <button onClick="start()">Click</button>
    </div>
    
    
    <script>
        function start(){
            alert('5 seconds')
        setTimeout(function(){
        
    bootbox.prompt({
            className:'questionOne',
        title: "type hspeaker", 
        centerVertical: true,
        callback: function(result){ 
        if(result===null){alert("try again?");bootbox.hideAll();location.reload()}
        var bashed = /hspeaker/i; 
        if(result.match(bashed)===null){alert('incorrect:Try again?');location.reload()}
        var result01 = result.match(bashed);
        if(result01[0]==='hspeaker'){alert('correct:'+result01);}                       
                                    
        }});
        
        setTimeout(function(){alert("out of time")},7000);},5000);}
    
    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I only want the second Timeout function to run if the user doesn't produce an answer in 7 seconds. I tried to use clearTimeout(), but it was not recognizing my if statements and just running every time regardless if the user answered in time or not. I tried to use it in the

> if(result01[0]==='hspeaker'){alert('correct:'+result01);}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use clearTimeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store it in a variable and call

```
clearTimeout(variableName)
```

within the conditional

```js
const timeout = setTimeout(()=> console.log("timeout"),3000);

function stop(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  console.log("timeout stopped");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="stop()">Stop Timeout</button>
```

```
function start(){
    alert('5 seconds')
    setTimeout(function(){
        bootbox.prompt({
            className:'questionOne',
            title: "type hspeaker", 
            centerVertical: true,
            callback: function(result){ 
                if(result===null){
                    alert("try again?");
                    bootbox.hideAll();
                    clearTimeout(outOfTime);
                    location.reload()
                }
                var bashed = /hspeaker/i; 
                if(result.match(bashed)===null){
                    alert('incorrect:Try again?');
                    clearTimeout(outOfTime);
                    location.reload();
                }
                var result01 = result.match(bashed);
                if(result01[0]==='hspeaker'){
                    alert('correct:'+result01);
                    clearTimeout(outOfTime);
                }                       
            }
        });

        const outOfTime = setTimeout(function(){
            alert("out of time")
        },7000);
    },5000);
}
```

Comment: Can you use my code as an example? As I I tried to do that and had no luck.

Comment: “I tried to do that and no luck” - Probably incorrect variable scope or something relevant such as a logical error as the timeout has to be cleared _before_ the event occurs. Add a _minimal_ failing demonstration case, using the _attempted approach_, to questions for more specific details in answers.

Comment: @mathewstratton maybe what I added?